# HDF5 C++ Qt conflicting declaration

Tags: c++, qt, declaration, hdf5

**Situation:** I need to read a `.hdf5` file and show the data graphically in an interface created with Qt.

**What i did:** I created a new project doing nothing but adding the `hdf5.lib` as an external library to the `hdf5_test.pro` using the the qt wizard for doing that and   `#include <hdf5.h>` in the `mainwindow.h`

**Problem:** 
When trying to run the code, i get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jktYO.png): `conflicting declaration 'typedef long long ssize_t'`

---

**Using:**

- C++
- Qt 5.10.1
- MinGW 5.3.0 32bit for C++
- HDF5 1.10.2

---

**My Code:**

```css
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <hdf5.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```css
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = hdf5_test
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5d
else:unix: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'
```

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085774/linking-hdf5-in-qt-with-mingw) might be a simillar problem, but there are no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack, but the hdf5.h checks for `H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T` to be equal to zero. So using a

```
#define H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T H5_SIZEOF_LONG_LONG
```

before including hdf5.h could help by not redefining the type.

Comment: This solved the problem for me but lead to a bunch of errors later. I compiled with MSVC17 and everything works fine.